# Power BI DAX to split the value in to multiple ranges

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the data as below.

```
Product     Channel Account_Id  Max_tier        Balance
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   4999.999        174589.26
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   9999.999        174589.26
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   19999.999       174589.26
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   49999.999       174589.26
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   99999999999.99  174589.26
```

I am trying to build a report in Power BI, where the Balance should be split into a range that should fit into MAX_TIER.So the output should be as below

```
Product     Channel Account_Id  Max_tier        Balance     Split_range
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   5000            174589.26   5000
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   10000           0           10000
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   20000           0           20000
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   50000           0           50000
2000-0100   Direct  102123625   99999999999.99  0           89589.26
```

Any thought would be much appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `Split_range` calculated column, you need to figure out what the cumulative total of the prior tier is. You can do this as follows:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Max_tier] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Product] ),
    Table1[Max_tier] < EARLIER ( Table1[Max_tier] )
)
```

That is, you add prior tiers where the `Product` is the same.

Having that, you just need to subtract out the cumulative total from balance if that number is positive and less than the current max.

```
Split_range =
VAR Cumulative =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table1[Max_tier] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Product] ),
        Table1[Max_tier] < EARLIER ( Table1[Max_tier] )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        Table1[Balance] > Cumulative,
        MIN ( Table1[Balance] - Cumulative, Table1[Max_tier] ),
        0
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexis, One clarification. The data related to MAX_tier is in another table which has Product_code as a relation to the main fact table. That means I have table 1 which has a product code, max_tier, and table2 productcode, balance, etc